# Custom facebook app doesn't work on a PC with IE 9 in some cases

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, facebook-apps

I build an app for Facebook, a very simple competition. But for some strange reason it works on mac's in all browsers, but not on PC at least IE 9, but to make it even stranger, on some PC's it does work in IE 9.
I just can't put my finger on the problem, and I can't find a similar problem.

Is there anyone who experienced the same sort of problem and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is has something to do with http and https. For a page tab app you also need to specify the url for users that have https enabled.